# "StartTag: invalid element name" in default.aspx

Tags: asp.net, iis

(Warning - asp newbie) I have an aspx file with the tag

```
    <%@ Page Language=VB  ... %>
```

right at the beginning of the file.

When calling this from my IIS server (http://localhost/myservice/default.aspx), this gives me the error

> This page contains the following
>   errors:
>
> error on line 1 at column 2:
>   StartTag: invalid element name
>   Below is a rendering of the page up to
>   the first error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: dont forget to add the .asmx extension to application mappings...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears as if the browser tries to display what it thinks is an XML file, since it gives an error on the second character of the first line. So I think the file is not parsed, but simply returned as is immediately. Check if your IIS server is configured correctly and that it actually parses your ASP tags before returning the page.

Comment: Yes, it sounds like ASP.NET isn't installed correctly in IIS.  If you can debug this page in VS, then that is definitely the issue.

Answer (score 6):

When I went into the ASP.NET tab for the virtual directory I noticed the ASP.NET version was not selected (it was an empty combo box). Choosing the .NET framework version did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the previous comment, in my setup too the ASP.NET version was not selected. But after selecting the version i got the following error while accessing the aspx file.
Windows XP, IIS 5.1.
Exception Details: System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironmentException: Failed to access IIS metabase.

Executed the following commands, aspnet_iis -i
and aspnet_iis -ga

resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

When i did this. It worked fine.

Go to this directroy in command prompt C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727 
Run this command 
Aspnet_regiis  -I

this will install aspnet

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

To install and enable ASP.NET:

Click Start, and then click Control Panel.
Click Add or Remove Programs.
Click Add/Remove Windows components.
Double-click Application Server, and then click Details.
Click to select the ASP.NET check box, and then click OK.
Click Next.
Click Finish.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was that I was viewing the .svc file using my local file path mapped to a server in my browser when I meant to be using the verbatim path to my server.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was in the serialization that responded to client.

My problem was in the xml tags spaces:

```
  - < tag > text < / tag >  ---> wrong

  - <tag> text </tag> ----> good.
```