# ASP.NET invalid element name StartTag error

Tags: asp.net

For some reason, I'm getting this error when trying to test a code page on my computer.

It may have something to do with a faulty IIS installation, but I can't seem to find out what the problem is.

I get the following error:

`error on line 1 at column 2: StartTag: invalid element name`

Here is my Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<html>

<head>

<title>Plating Trees</title>

<script runat=”server”>
 protected void Page_Load(Object Source, EventArgs E)
 {

/* Begin C# Code!*/

Tree tree1 = new Tree();

tree1.Grow(3);

tree1.Message();

 }

</script>

</head>

<body>

<p><asp:label runat=”server” id=”Output” /></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Tree.cs:

```
/* A simple C# class! */

public class Tree
{

    public int height = 0;

    public void Grow(int h)
    {
        height += h;
    }

    public string Message()
    {
        Output.Text = "The height of tree1 is:<br/>” + tree1.height + feet";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the cause of your issue, but the double quotes around your attributes and code don't look valid.

```
<script runat=”server”>
<p><asp:label runat=”server” id=”Output” /></p>
```

should be:

```
<script runat="server">
<p><asp:label runat="server" id="Output" /></p>
```

and

```
Output.Text = "The height of tree1 is:<br/>” + tree1.height + feet";
```

should be:

```
Output.Text = "The height of tree1 is:<br/>" + tree1.height + "feet";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is similar to this previous question in StackOverflow: [“StartTag: invalid element name” in default.aspx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281017/starttag-invalid-element-name-in-default-aspxThanks.), which seems like an IIS configuration issue.

From the link:

> When I went into the ASP.NET tab for
>   the virtual directory I noticed the
>   ASP.NET version was not selected (it
>   was an empty combo box). Choosing the
>   .NET framework version did the trick.

Have a look at it, it might solve your problem :)

Comment: Thanks, that helps too, however, I'm still having the problem! :)  I'm working it out though.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that your `Tree` class does not have access to `Output`, because that property belongs to a different object, `Default.aspx`.  You need to call `Output.Text` from `Default.aspx` instead of `Tree`.  Also, I think geoff is right about the **”** versus **"**.  Therefore, edit your `Page_Load` as follows:

**In your Default.aspx**

```
<script runat="server">
protected void Page_Load(Object Source, EventArgs E)
{
  /* Begin C# Code!*/
  Tree tree1 = new Tree();
  tree1.Grow(3);
  Output.Text = tree1.Message();
}
</script>
```

In `Message()` you need to remove `Output.Text`.  Next, you can't have the class `Tree` reference itself like `tree1.height`, so change it to either `this.height` or preferably just `height`.  Also, remove `feet` because you don't have it defined anywhere yet.  Note that you have a **”** in this method too.  Finally, take out the last **"** that was to the right of `feet`.  Edit as follows:

**In your `Test` class**

```
public string Message()
{
  return "The height of tree1 is:<br/>" + height;
}
```

You can keep everything else the same, but personally, I would move the `<script runat="server">` block to just below the `<%@ Page Language="C#" %>`

Also, I think you have bugs in your logic, but I'm sure you can figure that out once you get past this stuff.

*(I ran it from my VS 2008 IDE)*

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean bugs in my logic?  Do you mean the way I'm setting up the super simple "program"?

Comment: @BOSS: I meant that when I ran it, the output was not as you intended, because your `Message()` method is still off.  See my update for the solution.

Comment: @BOSS, as far as setting up this program, I think most ASP.NET programmer prefer to use the "Code Behind" page type so your methods are in a separate file called `Default.aspx.cs`

Answer (score 0):

@BOSS, perhaps you need to run aspnet_regiis tool to re-register ASP.NET in your IIS.

Go into your .NET framework command prompt and run "aspnet_regiis -i" to do this.

Reference: [ASP.NET IIS Registration Tool (Aspnet_regiis.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(VS.80).aspx)

Also, note the following if you have multiple website in your IIS:

> The -i flag causes the aspnet_regiis
>   command to perform its work on every
>   website on the box, not just the one
>   that needs it. As the .NET framework
>   2.0 begins to ship there will be more developers and production servers
>   running both version of the framework.
>   Running the aspnet_regiis command with
>   the -i flag will associate all
>   websites on the box with the framework
>   from where the command was run (there
>   is one version of the aspnet_regiis
>   command for every installed version of
>   the .NET framework). It is also useful
>   to note that the -i flag will reset
>   auto-generated values with immediate
>   impact on forms based logins and
>   viewstate checksums. If you run the
>   command with the -i flag on a live
>   production server you may very well
>   interupt the applications of logged in
>   users of other applications on the
>   same box. The “-i“ flavor of the
>   command should never be run in a
>   production environment unless there
>   are no active users logged on, and all
>   websites on the box happen to be on
>   the same .NET framework version.

From: [Running "aspnet_regiis -i" Not Always The Best Choice](http://geekswithblogs.net/paulmehner/archive/2005/08/03/48970.aspx)