# ASP.net webservice debugging problem - have tried numerous things!

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, iis

Been trying to create an ASP.net web service in IIS, however every time we try to run the newly created webservice we get the following error:

> Unable to start debugging on the web server. The web server is not configured correctly.

We have tried the following so far:

- Made sure that the website within IIS is using the correct version of ASP.net
- Made sure the following was in the web.config file `<compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="true" />`
- Made sure Windows integrated authentication was enabled in IIS
- Since IIS was installed after visual studio 2008 we have run ASPNET_REGIIS.EXE

Any help would be awesome as this has stuffed me up for close to a day now

Comment: You said "Made sure the following was in the web.config file".  What exactly?

Comment: FYI: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwesw3ee(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Sorry about that, all updated, Have been though that page extensively as well

Comment: What happens when you browse directly to the web service in your browser with debugging turned off?  (Or do Debug > Start Without Debugging?)  Is it on a local or remote server?

Comment: It's in IIS on localhost. When I start without debugging a page opens Directory Listing Denied

This Virtual Directory does not allow contents to be listed

Comment: After you start without debugging, browse directly to your web service.  For example if your web service file is YourService.asmx and your app starts at http://localhost:81/ then browse to http://localhost:81/YourService.asmx. Browsing directly to the web service can often uncover a configuration problem.

Comment: Appreciate the help on this one. There doesnt seem to be a port number as it is running from IIS/localhost. Going stragiht to the .asmx page returns the following error:
`This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1 at column 2: StartTag: invalid element name
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.`

I think this might be an IIS related issue?

Comment: Check out this for help with the "invalid element name" error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281017/starttag-invalid-element-name-in-default-aspx

Comment: I went to IIS and on my webservice ran the permissions wizard. I changed the Scenario to a public website and everything seems to work. As soon as I change it back to Secure website I then get the error again. I'm unsure what is incorrect in IIS when it comes to selecting "Secure Website"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all else fails, an easy workaround provided you can can indeed access the url OK - is to simply use the menu option in Visual Studio

Debug->Attach to Process

Find your worker process (aspnet_wp.exe on xp or w3wp.exe after)
you should then be able to debug without a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Adam. Had tried this as well and still no luck but have got at elast a temporary work around for the problem:

Comment: In IIS, right clicked on my site --> All Tasks --> Permissions Wizard --> Select new security settings from template --> Selected public website.

Everything now seems to work with no errors however being new to this I am unsure of the impact these settings have had.

Comment: interesting - what happened when you tried to attach the debugger? as long as you are running VS under proper permissions you should be able to attach - the only caveat then is if your .pdb file can be found/loaded.

Answer (score 0):

In IIS, right clicked on my site --> All Tasks --> Permissions Wizard --> Select new security settings from template --> Selected public website.

Everything now seems to work with no errors however being new to this I am unsure of the impact