# .net Publishing Error in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, publish

I'm developing a .net web project using Visual Studio 2010. I'm trying to publish locally the project using the File System method. But when accessing the default.aspx page from my web browser the following error is outputted:

> error on line 1 at column 2: StartTag: invalid element name

Related posts in this site didn't gave me a valid solution.

How can I solve this problem?

This is my Code:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="PresentationLayer._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>
        Main Page
    </h2>

       <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSpeech" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td>                 
                    <asp:Button ID="btnValidate" runat="server" Text="Validate" 
                        onclick="btnValidate_Click" ValidationGroup="Validations" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSpeach" runat="server" Text="Play" 
                        onclick="btnSpeach_Click" /></td>
                        <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btnNewText" runat="server" Text="New" onclick="btnNewText_Click" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblText" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblValidation" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                    </td> </tr>
                    <tr>


                    <td>

                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="txtSpeech" ErrorMessage="Required Field" 
                        ValidationGroup="Validations" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>                

                    <td>

                        <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" 
                            ControlToValidate="txtSpeech" ErrorMessage="Incorrect Input" ForeColor="Red" 
                            MaximumValue="15" MinimumValue="0" Type="Integer" ValidationGroup="Validations"></asp:RangeValidator>

                    </td>
                    </tr>


        </table>

    </asp:Content>
```

Comment: You'd get a much faster solution if you posted some code. What does the default.aspx page look like? I don't know, since you didn't tell us.

Comment: The page when debugged and ran in Visual Studio works well, so I Think is a publish properties problem!

Comment: If you post some code someone would be able to help you, otherwise any answer would be guessing.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["StartTag: invalid element name" in default.aspx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281017/starttag-invalid-element-name-in-default-aspx)

Comment: I already saw that post, but it didn't solved my issue

Comment: Code Added in the main thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get this error if I try to directly open the file from the file system in Google Chrome.  You actually need to host your site in IIS for it to work properly.  Then browse to the url setup in IIS.