# How can i call a .Aspx page in HTML page inside the iframe tag

Tags: asp.net, html, .net, c#-4.0

I have a html page and i want to add a aspx page into that html page how can i do this.
i used  tag but it is giving the error.
Please tell me what can i do.

my home.html contains the following

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
 <body>
<iframe id="ff" width="546px" height="500px" frameborder="0" scroll="no" src="Default.aspx"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

and default.aspx contains a source code

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="AgrawalPakcers._Default" %>

<HTML>

<HEAD>
 <LINK REL="stylesheet" HREF="style1.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA="screen">
</head>
<body>
    <form id="FORM2" runat="server">
  <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" ALIGN="CENTER" 
WIDTH="240">
  <TR>
    <TD VALIGN="TOP" ALIGN="LEFT">
    <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" ALIGN="CENTER" CLASS="tab2">
      <TR>
        <TD><B CLASS="c1">Shifting Type :</B><BR>
        <IMG SRC="gifs/zero.gif" WIDTH="80" HEIGHT="1"></TD>
        <TD><SELECT NAME="Services" STYLE="width:140px;font-size:11px; color:#333;height:20px;border:1px solid #F0D8A1;">
        <OPTION VALUE="NA">----- Select Services -----</OPTION>
        <OPTION VALUE="LOCAL">LOCAL</OPTION>
        <OPTION VALUE="DOMESTIC">DOMESTIC</OPTION>
        <OPTION VALUE="INTERNATIONAL">INTERNATIONAL</OPTION></SELECT></TD>
      </TR>
      <TR>
        <TD><B CLASS="c1">Name :</B></TD>
        <TD><INPUT NAME="S_name" SIZE="12" MAXLENGTH="40" VALUE="" STYLE="border:1px solid #F0D8A1; width:136px;" ONFOCUS="javascript:RegValue(this);" ONBLUR="javascript:RegValue1(this);" CLASS="txtfa"></TD>
      </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD><B CLASS="c1">Contact No. :</B></TD>
        <TD>
        <TABLE CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" BORDER="0">
          <TBODY>
          <TR>
            <TD><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="S_mcode" ID="S_mcode" SIZE="5" READONLY="READONLY" STYLE="width:30px;height:15px;" CLASS="txtfn" VALUE=""></TD>
            <TD><IMG SRC="gifs/zero.gif" WIDTH="2" HEIGHT="1"></TD>
            <TD><INPUT NAME="S_mobile" ID="S_mobile" TYPE="text" ONFOCUS="javascript:CellValue(this);" ONBLUR="javascript:CellValue1(this);" SIZE="15" VALUE="Mobile / Cell Phone Number" CLASS="txtfa" STYLE="width:103px;height:15px;"></TD>
          </TR></TBODY>
        </TABLE></TD>
      </TR>
      <TR>
        <TD><B CLASS="c1">E-Mail ID :</B></TD>
        <TD><INPUT NAME="S_email" MAXLENGTH="48" SIZE="12" VALUE="" STYLE="border:1px solid #F0D8A1;width:136px;" ONFOCUS="javascript:EmailValue(this);" ONBLUR="javascript:EmailValue1(this);" CLASS="txtfa"></TD>
      </TR>
      <TR>
        <TD><B CLASS="c1">From :</B></TD>
        <TD><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="from" SIZE="12" MAXLENGTH="60" VALUE="" STYLE="border:1px solid #F0D8A1;width:136px;" CLASS="txtfa" ONFOCUS="javascript:FromValue(this);" ONBLUR="javascript:FromValue1(this);"></TD>
      </TR>
  <TR>
            <TD COLSPAN="3">
            <CENTER><INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Submit"></CENTER></TD>
          </TR>

    </body>
    </html>
```

and when i browse home.html
i m getting the following error.

This page contais the following errors:
error on line 1 at column 2 : StartTag: invlid element name

Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Comment: is the same error is showing when you browse the aspx page directly?

Comment: yes this is the same error i m getting while browsing home.html

Comment: getting this error while debugging or on IIS?

Comment: Please refer to the answers in this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281017/starttag-invalid-element-name-in-default-aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have copy and paste you html and it is working fine, the problem is you have missed the closing tag of table and form. you should close you form and table tag then I think it will work.

have you kept home.html and Default.aspx file in same directory, If you don't then keep it in the same location.

Comment: no in my actual code i closed all the tags. and i kept all files in the same directory.