# ASP.NET website on Amazon cloud

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a asp.net web application. I need to upload the published files to AWS and get accessing it through a browser. I have downloaded S3 browser and and created my account using the access key and secret access key. Then i uploaded the published files to the desired bucket. But when i accessed Default.aspx, browser showed error :

This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1 at column 2: StartTag: invalid element name
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

I just checked uploading a sample html page to that path and i could access it successfully. Is there any thing that I need to do on EC2 to get my website up??

Comment: Are you trying to use S3 to serve your ASP site directly? S3 doesn't support dynamic content. It needs a server (ie an EC2 instance running Windows and IIS) to work. The error you are getting is your web browser trying to interpret ASP markup directly as HTML code.

Comment: EC2 instance is running Windows Server 2008 R2 and has IIS 7 on that. Do i need AWS SDK for accessing aspx pages?

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood your question. But the underlying cause is still the same - your browser is getting an XML file from your webserver. See my answer for more details.

Comment: No you shouldn't need the SDK, you're just trying to server an ASP project from your server.

Answer (score 1):

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/281039/808532):

> It appears as if the browser tries to display what it thinks is an XML
>   file, since it gives an error on the second character of the first
>   line. So I think the file is not parsed, but simply returned as is
>   immediately. Check if your IIS server is configured correctly and that
>   it actually parses your ASP tags before returning the page.

You might have a configuration issue in IIS. Try [re-registering ASP.Net with IIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) on your server using the following from the command-line:

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

The exe file is located under the appropriate framework version on the server in the following directory:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework
```

Also make sure the version of `aspnet_regiis` you use is the same as your application's app pool framework version in IIS.

Comment: I did re register IIS, but i couldn't find my application in IIS. I have uploaded it with S3 browser.