# Deploy website with libraries

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I've been trying to publish a website in asp.net, but when I go to Build/Publish, all I can publish is the webApp, but I have libraries in another folder that I need to include, here you have the visual studio solution explorer: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3b7Z.jpg

The thing is that I somehow need to include "AcademUALibrary" in the
   project in order to be able to upload the website to 1and1, but I
   don't know how to do it. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

If your web project references the AcademUALibrary project, publishing the project should include the necessary libraries in the bin folder automatically. Have you verified that it's not publishing correctly? If it compiles and runs on your development computer, it should publish properly without any special configuration.

Comment: It is referenced, I added a reference, but after publishing it with the file system method, when I try to open it I get this error: http://imgur.com/6XTXFt7

Comment: That's not the error you would get for an unreferenced library. Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/281017/144604

Comment: Have you added a bin folder containing all the necessary dll's to your project?