# ASP.NET Web Form fails to parse

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to create a very simple .aspx web form with a great amount of difficulty. I can see my web page perfectly when debugging, however, when I publish it to a file system (my desktop) and open the web page, it returns this error:

```
**This page contains the following errors:**

*error on line 1 at column 2: StartTag: invalid element name*

**Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.**
```

*I'm using Visual Studio 2015 (Update 2) on 4.6.2 .NET framework.*

**Things I have tried:**

- Running aspnet_regiis -i in  CMD
- Using WebPI 5.0 to install components I might not have had before
- Enabling all the IIS & .NET features in the Control Panel

Also, may be unrelated, but when I try to publish it to my website via FTP directly through .VS it crashes the program.

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/a/281056/30594

Comment: @Ramesh yes, I have. Followed the appropriate steps on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6cw6cfs.aspx to no avail.

Comment: This is about configuring the .NET framework for the specific web application

Comment: @Ramesh how may I do that? First time working with this stuff

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754523(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: @Ramesh I have also done that.