# PHP Error “Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.”

Tags: php, html, xml, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

I'm unable to find the solution. Please help.

```
<?php 
    include_once ('../includes/config.php');
    include_once ('../includes/db_connect.php');
    include_once ('../includes/site_info.php');
    $settings_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM settings");
    $settings = mysql_fetch_array($settings_query);

if($settings['sitemap_enable'] == 1) {

header("Content-type: text/xml");

echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';

?>

<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
  xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1" xml:lang="en">

    <url>
        <loc><?=$settings['website_url'];?></loc>
        <lastmod><?=date("Y-m-d");?></lastmod>
        <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
        <priority>1.0</priority>
    </url>

    <?php
    $categories = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE status='on'");

    while($cat = mysql_fetch_assoc($categories)) {
        $id = $cat['id'];
        $name = $cat['name'];
        $cat_id = $cat['cat_id'];

    echo "<url>
                <loc>" . $settings['website_url'] . "/" . $cat_id . "</loc>
                <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
                <priority>1.0</priority>
          </url>";

    }

$SETTINGS['SQL'] = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM settings ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1");
while($SETTINGS = mysql_fetch_array($SETTINGS['SQL'])) {

    $entries = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE status='on'");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($entries)) {
        $id = $row['id'];         
        $news_id = $row['news_id'];
        $title_1  = $row['title'];
        $title = str_replace('&', '&amp;', $title_1);
        $file  = $row['file'];
        $old_date = $row['date'];

$cat_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id=".$row['cat'].""); $cat_row = mysql_fetch_row($cat_query); if($cat_row['2'] == '') { $cat_row = 'other'; }else{ $cat_row=$cat_row['2']; } if($SETTINGS['permalink'] == 'gag') { $link = "/gag/".$news_id; } elseif($SETTINGS['permalink'] == 'cat') { $link = "/".$cat_row."/".$news_id; } elseif($SETTINGS['permalink'] == 'cat_slugify') { $link = "/".$cat_row."/".$row['news_id']; }

    echo "<url>
                <loc>" . $settings['website_url'] . $link . "</loc>
                <lastmod>".$old_date."</lastmod>
                <image:image><image:loc>". $settings['website_url'] . "/uploads/media_photos/" . $file . "</image:loc><image:caption>". $title . "</image:caption><image:title>". $title . "</image:title></image:image>
                <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
                <priority>1.0</priority>
          </url>";

 } 

}?>

</urlset>

<? } else {
    header("Location: " . $settings['website_url']);
} ?>
```

File connect.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
#error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

// Database info
define('DATABASE_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DATABASE_NAME', '***');
define('DATABASE_USERNAME', '***');
define('DATABASE_PASSWORD', '***');
define('ADMIN_NAME', '***');
define('ADMIN_PASSWORD', '***');


// Installation url
define('URL', ''); // eg: http://***

// Email
define('EMAIL', '****');

// HTTP HOST
define('HTTP', 'http://***.com/');
?>
```

I keep getting this error:

> This page contains the following errors:
>
> error on line 583 at column 120: StartTag: invalid element name
>   Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Comment: Stop using the `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated since v5.5 (Jun 2013) and removed since v7.0 (Dec 2015). Instead use the [**mysqli_***](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) functions with [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["StartTag: invalid element name" in default.aspx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281017/starttag-invalid-element-name-in-default-aspx)

Comment: i changed them but it does not work. there is another problem then writing mysql or mysqli.